# Finding all Spanish words with given vowel patterns

Tags: function-construction, text, dictionary

I'm trying to implement a function using `DictionaryLookup` that does the following:

- Uses a Spanish dictionary
- Lists and counts of all words where the 5 vowels appear in any order
- Lists and counts of all words where the 5 vowels appear in a specific order
- Lists and counts of all the words with repeated vocal

Can you help me?

Comment: @Xavier The way he formulated the last makes me think the second shouldn't contain words with more then 5 vowels

Comment: @Coolwater I see. Then the following should satisfy this requirement: `DictionaryLookup[{"Spanish", 
  Alternatives @@ (StringExpression @@ 
       Riffle[#, 
        Except["a" | "e" | "i" | "o" | "u", _] ..., {1, -1, 2}] & /@ 
     Permutations[{"a", "e", "i", "o", "u"}])}]`

Comment: Thanks reviewing. Could you explain a little code

Answer (score 2):

```
 vovels = {"a", "e", "i", "o", "u"};

 dic = DictionaryLookup[{"Spanish", All}];

Length@dic
```

> 86016

**5 vowels in any order**

```
AllVowelsQ[str_String] :=
 FreeQ[Map[StringFreeQ[str, #] &, vovels], True]

{Length@#, #}&@Select[dic, AllVowelsQ] // Short
```

[image]

**Repeated vowels**

```
RepeatedVovelsQ[str_String] :=
 Max@Map[StringCount[str, #] &, vovels] >= 2

{Length@#, #}&@Select[dic, RepeatedVocalsQ] // Short
```

[image]

**5 vowels in a specific order**

```
(per = Permutations[vovels]) // Short
```

[image]

For example with

```
per[[2]]
```

> {"a", "e", "i", "u", "o"}

we get

```
Extract[dic, Position[True]@
  Map[Cases[Characters[#], Alternatives @@ vovels] == per[[2]] &, dic]]
```

> {"aceituno", "arseniuro", "cabeciduro"}